# Custom Product Collection not Getting Filtered by Layered Navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, layered-navigation

I had Overridden the product List.php Class & here is the code

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{   
  if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {

    $result = array_unique($productIds);        

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);
    $collection->addIdFilter($result);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);

    $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

working fine, I also had added Layered Navigation as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726891/magento-layered-navigation-on-custom-product-collection) and layered navigation appeared as expected.

The only problem is, when I click on any filter in layered navigation, navigation gets updated and filter also get added to url, but product list won't get filtered by the selected filter.
Please guide me how can I apply the filters on product collection

Comment: Is any1 facing the same issue in Magento2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong here, but your overridden `_getProductCollection()` method seems to be bypassing the layered navigation. I don’t know what your goal was that required you to do that, but the original version gets the product collection injected from the layered navigation model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer`:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        ...

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
            if ($category->getId()) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
        $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps you should revert to the original version of this method and see if layered navigation starts working, and if so then you know that you need to extend or incorporate this layer logic into your version.

Comment: I reverted magento to it's original version, the products are still not listed.